# Why does my Srand() never chooses 2 when i choose 1?

Tags: c

I created a Game in c of rock, paper & scissors.
The problem is whenever i choose 1, my com never ever chooses anything other than 0 and 1.
You can simply win the game everytime by choosing 1,2,1 or Rock,paper,rock

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <time.h>

int com;

int rng(int com)
{

    srand(time(NULL));
    return rand() %com;
}

int Uscore = 0;

int Cscore = 0;

int main()
{

    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <=10; i++)
    {
        int user;
        printf("the computer chose %d\n", rng(2));
        printf("enter 0 for rock \nenter 1 paper \nenter 2 for scissors \n");
        scanf("%d", &user);

        if (com != user)
        {
            if (com == 0 && user == 1 || com == 1 && user == 2 || com == 2 && user == 0)
            {
                Uscore++;
            }
            else
                Cscore++;
        }
        else 
        printf("its a draw\n");
    }
    if (Uscore > Cscore)
    {
        printf("You won");
    }
        else 
        printf("you lost");
    }
```

**strong text**

Comment: `srand` is only supposed to be called once for the entire program. [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once)

Comment: The `com` in `main` is the global variable `com`, which is always 0.

Comment: You need to save the choice the computer makes. 
Unrelated: Isn't it a bit like cheating that you show the computers choice _before_ asking what the user chooses?

Answer (score 4):

- `srand(time(NULL));`: Seeding the pseudo-random number generator only needs to happen once, so only call `srand(...)` once at the start of the program. Otherwise, calling `rng` twice within a very short window will result in the same not-so-random number.
- `return rand() %com;`: `com` needs to be 3 to generate a 0, 1, or 2. The modulo operator (`%`) is basically taking the remainder of a division.
- The result of `rng(2)` (which should be `rng(3)`) is only used for printing. It is never actually written to `com`. It is better to rename the parameter of the `rng` function to avoid confusion, and declare `com` inside the `main` function.

E.g. modify this part like this:

```
int user;
int com = rng(3);
printf("the computer chose %d\n", com);
```

Answer (score 2):

when call rng function, need to pass 3 as parameter not 2. The return value could be 0, 1, 2.